# Convert bcrypt-hashed password to MD5-hashed

Tags: google-app-engine, single-sign-on, md5, bcrypt

I have a learning management system (Moodle) that has an SSO to Google Apps. It's supposed to create a new user in Google Apps whenever a new user is created in the LMS. However, whenever I create a new user, I get this error:

> Error(1402): Error 1402: InvalidPassword Invalid Input:
>   "$2y$10$LAz7FBoqT4aKa/AAWeA.seKF3GrpqEu1COOipgvUAw6Fcj5LmiYVW"

The long string in the error is the bcrypt-hashed password, which is how my LMS stores passwords. However, Google Apps requires that user passwords be hashed with MD5 or SHA-1. I know almost nothing about hashing. Is there a way to convert the bcrypt-hashed passwords to MD5 or SHA-1?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you want to is impossible.

To do that would require taking the bcrypt hashed password and getting pack to the original plaintext password so that you could apply the MD5 or SHA1 to it.

But the whole point of a secure hash algorithm like bcrypt-hash is that it is a *one way function*, it is impossible (for practical purposes) to get back the original plaintext.

Comment: I know I can't revert to the ORIGINAL password before I hash it with MD5. I'm wondering if I can hash the bcrypted password with MD5 so that it's in the right format for Google Apps. Something like MD5(bcrypt(password)).

Comment: i am pretty sure that wont work either. as the string u get before md5ing is encripted by bcrypt, the final string after applying md5 wont get validated as md5 either.